# Parsing and printing X.509 attributes from PEM

Tags: go, x509, pem

I'm looking for a simple example for parsing an X.509 PEM in go and dumping the values to stdout. Can anybody provide an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`encoding.pem`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/) to decode the pem file, which will give you the DER blocks you can decode with the [`crypto/x509`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/) package.

For example:

```
certPEMBlock, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var blocks [][]byte
for {
    var certDERBlock *pem.Block
    certDERBlock, certPEMBlock = pem.Decode(certPEMBlock)
    if certDERBlock == nil {
        break
    }

    if certDERBlock.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
        blocks = append(blocks, certDERBlock.Bytes)
    }
}

for _, block := range blocks {
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    fmt.Println("Certificate:")
    fmt.Printf("\tSubject: %+v\n", cert.Subject)
    fmt.Printf("\tDNS Names: %+v\n", cert.DNSNames)
    fmt.Printf("\tEmailAddresses: %+v\n", cert.EmailAddresses)
    fmt.Printf("\tIPAddresses: %+v\n", cert.IPAddresses)
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks you - all the examples included many things that I didn't need so I couldn't see the wood from the trees.

Comment: Actually one other question. If I need to get the readable values from the OIDS in the extensions. e.g. ` Extensions: [{Id:2.5.29.19 Critical:true Value:[48 6 1 1 255 2 1 0]} {Id:2.5.29.15 Critical:true Value:[3 2 1 6]} {Id:2.5.29.14 Critical:false Value:[4 20 130 58 82 76 175 51 150 249 100 78 198 192 222 152 125 138 116 43 190 57]} {Id:2.5.29.35 Critical:false Value:[48 22 128 20 193 119 177 45 157 107 253 81 197 19 136 6 147 96 30 135 125 249 52 15]}]` Is there an easy way to get them ?

Comment: @user1513388: I'm not sure what you mean. You already have them; they're decoded as a [`pkix.Extension`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/pkix/#Extension).

Comment: The ID's and extensions are being returned as ID's and Values. e.g. {Id:2.5.29.19 Critical:true Value:[48 6 1 1 255 2 1 0]}

Comment: @user1513388: I'm not sure of an easy way to match OID to name, but you can copy the defined values out of the x509 source (search for "oidExtension" in [x509.go](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/x509.go))